# Swift/Xcode: Why would PFUser.currentuser() not be returning nil if logged out?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I wanted to set up a conditional segue (in Swift/Xcode, with parse-server framework, hosted by Heroku) that will perform only if the current user has not logged out. It works appropriately if the user has not logged out. However, even if the user logs out, the segue will still run. Here is a basic set up of the code.

I call the user to log out via:

```
PFUser.logoutinbackground()
```

However, the segue:

```
If PFUser.currentuser() != nil {

//perform segue
}
```

will still perform the segue. Printing the PFUser.currentuser() to logs does not return nil. If I rewrite the conditional segue code to this:

```
If PFUser.currentuser()?.username != nil {
//perform segue
}
```

This works appropriately, returning PFUse.currentuser()?.username to the logs does return nil. Is there anything particularly wrong with leaving it like this (ie. will this cause any problems?). Also, why wouldn't it be return nil for the first version of the segue code? Does it have to do with the fact that I called PFUser.loginoutinbackground() as opposed to PFUser.logout() (the latter causes the app to crash for some reason)?

Answer (score 2):

`PFUser.logOut();` This logs the user out immediately. When you call `PFUser.logoutinbackground()` does not log the user out immediately.

```
PFUser.logoutinbackground()
if PFUser.currentuser() != nil {

//perform segue
}
```

`logoutinbackground()` is async.  That is why the code above will not do what you think it should do.  I always use `PFUser.logOut();`

**Update**

Make sure that you do not have this in your code

```
PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()
```

Comment: the app closes upon me using this command (PFUser.logOut()). Do you have any idea why this might be the case? Not sure why it has trouble with it.

Comment: yes there is. But I am not at my computer that contains the app at the moment. I will post it as soon as I can. Thanks for the help

Comment: an additional comment before I can post the error. Even if the inbackground command is async... I do not call the conditional statement for the segue until I close out the simulator/app and then restart it after the logoutinbackground is called. Its async, but the conditional segue is not called until the app is restarted... does this still follow your answer?

Comment: With you using logoutinbackground() parse decides when it is best to log you out and if you call logoutinbackground() and quit the app the call may be getting canceled by the OS. If you use logout() that call is made on the main thread which has to happen right then.

Comment: I used the logout() call, and the problem persisted. Printing the PFUser.currentuser() doesn't return nil. It has an object ID, though none of the classes that I have in the DB. Is there an issue with having my conditional segue set to the PFUser.currentuser()?.username? Because that is nil.

Comment: What parse version are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118944/discussion-between-brett-ponder-and-alek-piasecki).